# OUTPUT TO csv file - SQL Anywhere using pyodbc gives error

Tags: python, file, csv, sqlanywhere

I am using the following query with pyodbc:

```
def generiere():
    query = """SELECT ArtikelNr, Artikel_Bezeichnung, Artikel_Menge, System_created, Summen_netto, Summen_brutto, Summen_ust_gesamt FROM FK_AuftragPos;OUTPUT TO 'C:/Users/User/Documents/Software/Statistik/test.csv' FORMAT TEXT QUOTE '"' DELIMITED BY ';' WITH COLUMN NAMES"""
    cursor.execute(query)
```

When I use this query in Interactive SQL it all works. But when I try to use it in my Python program I get the following error:

Syntax error at 'OUTPUT' ... (-131) (SQLExecDirectW)

I just do not know what I am doing wrong.

Edit: Provided more code and information.

Comment: Please check that you can connect - by doing the select statement and then reading the results in python. Also, please add to your code snippet the parts where you execute the statement (and commit, if you do).

Comment: I added the function I use to execute the query. Yes, I can connect to the database and read results in Python.

Answer (score 0):

the last part of your query `;OUTPUT TO 'C:/Users/User/Documents/Software/Statistik/test.csv' FORMAT TEXT QUOTE '"' DELIMITED BY ';' WITH COLUMN NAMES` is not valid syntax for the query

it might be valid in an interactive console to the db, but that are then commands from the interactive console

Comment: you should do the resultset parsing and file writing yourself in python

Comment: This is a rather large dataset(about 300 Mb). I found it to be faster to let the database output the results to the csv file. It is just a syntax error. It should be easily fixable.

Comment: `description = cursor.description` gives you the column names and `result_set = cursor.fetchall()` gives you the data so `result_set[0][0]` is the first column of the first row

Comment: if you want the output to be parsed by the interactive console, then you might call that one with `subprocess.call`